# Selecting specific parts of a text string for editing

Tags: php

Not sure about the terminology as I am not generally working with strings, but here is my problem.
I am selecting the contents of a third party's text files through this code:

```
$fh = fopen($filename, 'r');
$upgradedata = fread($fh, filesize($filename));
fclose($fh);
```

The text I obtain is fairly long and follows a fairly regular pattern. Here is an extract:

```
UpgradeType="Parc Ferme Reset"
{

UpgradeLevel="Race Setting"
{
    Description="Default setting"
}
UpgradeLevel="Parc Ferme Reset"
{   
    Description="Reset setting"
}
}

UpgradeType="2014 Engine Development"
{
UpgradeLevel="Package #1 - Pre-Season Test #1"
{
Description="23/01 - Pre-Season Test #1"   
    Price=0

}
UpgradeLevel="Package #2 - Australian Grand Prix"
{
 Description="24/02 - Australian Grand Prix"
 Price=0

HDV=[ENGINE]
HDV=GeneralPowerMult*=1.0102459
HDV=EngineBoostRange=(0, 1, 2)
HDV=FuelConsumption*=0.9625  
HDV=
}
}
```

All sections start with an "UpgradeType" category, and have subcategories all starting with "UpgradeLevel".

What I am trying to do is:
1) find the category "UpgradeType="2014 Car Development""
2) count the subcategories "UpgradeLevel" within it.
3) append a new subcategory at the end of it, which I have already created and is contained in a $datastring variable.

Me and my team have been at it for the whole weekend - elsewhere, we use getElementsByTagName but the absence of tags (and our inability to change the original files as they're from a third party) means that this avenue is precluded.

Any pointer on which way to move - even if it is just a link to a function description - is appreciated!

Comment: Do you have to use this specific type of reading files? You could migrate to a more common type like the quite similar JSON, which already has libraries for reading and writing.

Comment: Hi Jeroen, do you mean the procedure to read the files? I am not bound to any specific system (I am using this as that was the easiest/first I found) so I can use something different if more convenient.

Comment: I'm more referring to the way the data is serialized. How it is formatted.

Comment: So long as the order of the elements and the { are in place, formatting is pretty much irrelevant to those files, so I assume it can be changed. The current format shown above is the original one from the .ini file.

Comment: In that case, have a look at JSON. It's a wide-spread serialization language, and PHP has implemented it by default. http://php.net/json

Comment: Thank you, checking it out right now!